# I cannot initialize class in python

Tags: python, class

I have a class Flight, and I'm trying initialize it, but I have a syntax error in

```
print x=Flight(flightFromInput='nebrasca')
```

This is a content of my example file

```
class Flight:
    flightFrom = None
    flightTo = None
    departureDate = None
    arrivalDate=None
    airline=None
    serviceClass=None
    departureAirport = None
    arrivalAirport=None


    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self,flightFromInput):
        self.flightFrom = flightFromInput

print x=Flight(flightFromInput='nebrasca')
```

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: it's always a good idea to write what error u get.

Comment: Also: Do you realize that variables created in class scope (in your code, every assignment above `#-----...`) are *class variables*, i.e. shared among instances, and not instance variables (`self....`)?

Comment: @delnan: The class variables can act as fall-backs.  If you assign to `.flightFrom` on an instance, you won't change the class variable, so semantically this is ok.  (You might have objections regarding the style, though.)

Comment: @Sven: That why I asked "do you realize" instead of writng "your code is propably broken". But yes, I do wonder if this is the best solution.

Comment: What makes you think that `print x=expression` will work?  Where have you seen Python syntax like that?  What tutorial are you using?

Comment: @S.Lott: It's not entirely unreasonable to expect assignment to be an expression (there are many popular languages that do this). Especially given that OP seems to know some of those (e.g. asked C# questions).

Comment: @Sven, I didn't know about self. I'm a c# developer so for me this way which I wrote is more natural. But I'll change this to self. thx

Comment: @delnan I saw at http://www.wellho.net/mouth/1146_-new-v-init-python-constructor-alternatives-.html something like  print C() and this is a source of my stupid command :)

Comment: @delnan: "reasonable" doesn't apply to any programming language I've ever seen.  They all have "unreasonable" features.  My question is "why assume that?"  What is the basis for the assumption?  It can't be random wishful thinking, can it?  Surely people don't irrationally assume features in programming languages.  So, what's the rational basis for this assumption?  I'm guessing that there's an example or a tutorial that's misleading.

Comment: @S.Lott: It seems you're totally missing my point. (1) Many programming languages treat assignment as an expression. (2) Python is a programming language, and not the most exotic at it. (3) Someone knowing 1 and 2 (but not that Python doesn't satisfy 1 - because it wasn't mentioned in the little material on the language they've read so far) could go ahead and assume 1 applies to Python as well, and try it.

Comment: @delnan: I'm not "missing" your point.  I don't believe that people make irrational assumptions about programming languages.  You claim they do.  I'm asking for clarification on this question.  What was the basis for the assumption.  I don't believe in irrational assumptions about programming languages.  You do.  I need evidence as to this being irrational or having some basis in a fact somewhere.

Comment: @S.Lott: See (1). The idea that X should be possible carries over from other languages that do X. And for this particular X (treating assignemnt as expression), most popular language do X!

Comment: @delnan: If it's not backed up by facts (i.e., a tutorial, a code example or the reference manual) it sure seems irrational to me.  But I guess you could somehow right.  Somehow a random, fact-free assumptions could somehow be rational.  It doesn't make any sense to me, but you keep repeating it.  I'm hoping for a better explanation, or a code sample or tutorial that makes the assumption fact-based and therefore rational.

Comment: @S.Lott: I'm not claiming it's wise to go and assume an unknown thing works like you expect it to. But people do it, and it's *not entirely unreasonable* (contrast with *totally rational and justified by facts*). When you learn a new language, don't you want to know what features you already know from other languages? For example, nested functions. Of course you will know shortly thereafter - because you'll look it up or try it out. OP did just that.

Comment: @delnan: "OP did just that".  Really?  Do you have a fact that I missed?  It sounds irrational to me.  I find it unreasonable.  Perhaps I've been burned too often.    I'm hoping for a definitive answer.  Can you provide a quote or something to substantiate your claim for what the OP did?

Comment: @S.Lott: Looking at the link OP gave, there are examples like `print C()`. Either we have to assume OP thinks a function call(/class instanciation) is totally the same things as assignment, or that OP thinks the two are both valid expressions. (Which sounds more *unreasonable*?) And no, I cannot prove you that OP then wrote the code we can see in the question, *tried it out* and noticed it doesn't work - but I'd love to hear a reasonable alternative theory.

Comment: @delnan: I don't want an alternative theory as much as I want an answer from @user278618  to my question "What makes you think that print x=expression will work?"

Comment: @S.Lott: Have you seen comment no. 8? "@delnan I saw at wellho.net/mouth/… something like print C() and this is a source of my stupid command :)" (Not adressed at you and not a full answer, but a start)

Comment: @delnan: "Have you seen comment no. 8?"  Yes.  I was happy with that answer.  However, you had some other issues you wanted to raise about assumptions.  Interesting stuff.  But not what I was asking about.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should write

```
x = Flight(flightFromInput='nebrasca')
print x
```

Answer (score 4):

In python an assignment statement doesn't return the assigned value. So you cannot use it within another statement. As the other answers suggested, you can work around this by printing `x` in a separate line.

Note, that there are exceptions though:

```
a = b = 0 # works
a = (b = 0) # does not work
```

The first case is a special case allowed for convenience when you want to assign the same value to multiple variables. In the second case you clearly tell the compiler that `b=0` is a separate statement, but as it doesn't return a value the outer assignment to `a` leads to the resulting SyntaxError.

Hope this explains it a bit more clearly, why you should do `print x` after assigning it.

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to C, in Python assignments are statements *only* and not expressions. Therefore they do not have their own value. Try this:

```
x = Flight(flightFromInput='nebrasca')
print x
```